# TFS Deployer Cross Domain

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am having trouble getting [TFS Deployer](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=tfsdeployer) to work over two domains.

I have two domains, DEVDOM and TFSDOM.  TFS Deployer is installed on DEVDOM machine and I have entered in the correct settings for authenticating against TFSDOM

TfsDeployer.exe.config:

```
...

    <setting name="TfsUserName" serializeAs="String">
            <value>acetinic</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="TfsDomain" serializeAs="String">
            <value>APACKF</value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="TfsPassword" serializeAs="String">
            <value>street10</value>
    </setting>

...
```

I am using this command : TfsDeployer.exe -d and get the following error:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerException: TF50309: The following a
ccount does not have sufficient permissions to complete the operation: DEVDOM\admin. The following permissions are needed to perform this operation: View col
lection-level information.
```

It's like as if it is not reading the authentication settings I am putting in my config.

Am I missing something ?

Also, when I want to start this as a service in Services, what account do I Log On as ? just local systems account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Was a bug with TFS Deployer.

http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=230367&ANCHOR#Post505355

Fixed in trunk